# How to authenticate users using g+ asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, google-plus, dotnetopenauth

My website uses DotNetOpenAuth to authenticate users with their Gmail account. In login.aspx.cs I use the user's email to check their status in a database.

I need to update this to google-plus but I haven't found any examples using DotNetOpenAuth. I was able to get the user's email using the instructions I found here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button

Examples I found suggest using a hidden form field, but I understand this isn't secure. Can you point me to some examples of doing the above, or recommend another method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My login.aspx has this reference to this js file
'<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/openid-en.js"></script>'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using the [Google+ quickstart for .NET](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/csharp). This sample app does two things:

1. Uses the Javascript client to authorize the client against Google APIs.
2. Passes the authorization code to the server to authorize the server for backend API calls.

You should be able to start from there as an example of the basics for authorization.

For authentication, you will need to retrieve an ID token and [pass that ID token from the client to the server to authenticate the user](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect#authenticatingtheuser).

Comment: Thanks Glass, looking at this now. Much appreciated.

Comment: This sample app requires MANY changes in order to get working with a typical webforms app. I would not recommend it

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by visiting the Google developer console and setting up a project. 
I configured credentials, the client id key and the OAuth consent screen. 
Next I added these lines to my login page. Basically, I get the user's gmail address and pass that to my database to confirm their permissions.

```
            <!--this is my google plus button-->
            <fieldset style="padding-left: 12px; width: 526px;">
                <legend style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size: small; font-weight: normal; ">
                    Welcome to my web app...
                </legend>
                    <br />
                <span id="signinButton">
                    <span
                    class="g-signin"
                    data-callback="LoginCallback"
                    data-clientid="client id key goes here"
                    data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
                    data-requestvisibleactions="http://schema.org/AddAction"
                    data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email">
                    </span>
                </span>
                <br />
            </fieldset>

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                function LoginCallback(authResult){
                    if (authResult['status']['signed_in']){
                        // get user's email address
                        gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function (){
                            gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function (resp){
                                var email = resp.email;
                                // call codebehind webmethod to validate user email in DB                                    
                                PageMethods.AuthenticateMember(email, MemberPass(email), MemberFail);
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
                    }
                }
```